# share point list and columns update,delete and modify using c#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a code using c# which creates and modifies my columns inside a `list`.

But whenever I run my code for some modification, same column is repeatedly created.

THIS IS MY CODE-

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Bulk_Site_Update {
    public partial class Form1: Form {

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Createcalsite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            using(SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(txtPWAUrl.Text)) {
                oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                using(SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb()) {
                    oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    foreach(SPWeb projsite in oSPWeb.Webs) {
                        if (projsite.WebTemplate.ToString().ToLower() == "projectsite") {
                            if (projsite.Title == "Proj1") {

                                SPList lst = projsite.Lists[txtListName.Text];

                                if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Singleline") {
                                    SPFieldText fldName = (SPFieldText) lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                    SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                    fldName.MaxLength = 200;
                                    lst.Fields.Add(fldName);
                                }
                                if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Number") {
                                    SPFieldNumber fldEmpID = (SPFieldNumber) lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                    SPFieldType.Number.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                    fldEmpID.DisplayFormat = SPNumberFormatTypes.NoDecimal;
                                    lst.Fields.Add(fldEmpID);
                                }
                                if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Date") {
                                    SPFieldDateTime fldDob = (SPFieldDateTime) lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                    SPFieldType.DateTime.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                    fldDob.DisplayFormat = SPDateTimeFieldFormatType.DateOnly;
                                    lst.Fields.Add(fldDob);
                                }
                                if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Currency") {
                                    SPFieldCurrency fldSal = (SPFieldCurrency) lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                    SPFieldType.Currency.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                    fldSal.Currency = SPCurrencyFieldFormats.UnitedStates;
                                    fldSal.DisplayFormat = SPNumberFormatTypes.TwoDecimals;

                                    lst.Fields.Add(fldSal);
                                }
                                if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Multiline") {
                                    SPFieldMultiLineText fldMulti = (SPFieldMultiLineText) lst.Fields.CreateNewField(SPFieldType.Note.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                    lst.Fields.Add(fldMulti);
                                }
                                if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Choice") {
                                    string fieldStatusName = lst.Fields.Add(txtColumnName.Text, SPFieldType.Choice, false);
                                    SPFieldChoice fieldStatus = (SPFieldChoice) lst.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldStatusName);
                                    string[] activityTypes = txtMultiline.Text.Split(',');
                                    fieldStatus.Choices.AddRange(activityTypes);
                                    fieldStatus.DefaultValue = txtMultilineDefault.Text.Split(',')[0];
                                    fieldStatus.Update();

                                }
                                if (cmbUpdatevalue.SelectedItem == "UpdateText") {
                                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                    query.Query = string.Concat(
                                        "<Where><Eq>",
                                        "<FieldRef Name=" + txtColumnName.Text + "/>",
                                        "<Value Type='Text'>" + txtOldvalue.Text + "</Value>",
                                        "</Eq></Where>");
                                    query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

                                    SPListItemCollection it = lst.GetItems(query);
                                    foreach(SPListItem item in it) {
                                        item[txtColumnName.Text] = txtNewvalue.Text;
                                        item.Update();
                                    }
                                }
                                if (cmbUpdatevalue.SelectedItem == "UpdateChoice") {

                                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                                    query.Query = string.Concat(
                                        "<Where><Eq>",
                                        "<FieldRef Name=" + txtColumnName.Text + "/>",
                                        "<Value Type='Choice'>" + txtOldvalue.Text + "</Value>",
                                        "</Eq></Where>");
                                    query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

                                    SPListItemCollection it = lst.GetItems(query);
                                    foreach(SPListItem item in it) {
                                        item[txtColumnName.Text] = txtNewvalue.Text;
                                        item.Update();
                                    }
                                }

                                if (cmbUpdatevalue.SelectedItem == "UpdateFormulae") {
                                    SPFieldCalculated calculatedField1 = (SPFieldCalculated) lst.Fields[txtColumnName.Text];
                                    calculatedField1.Formula = txtmodifiedformulae.Text;
                                    calculatedField1.Update();

                                }

                                if (cmbUpdatevalue.SelectedItem == "RemoveChoice") {
                                    SPFieldChoice chFldCategory = (SPFieldChoice) lst.Fields[txtColumnName.Text];
                                    chFldCategory.EditFormat = SPChoiceFormatType.Dropdown;
                                    chFldCategory.Choices.Remove(txtRemoveChoice.Text);
                                    //chFldCategory.Update();
                                }



                                SPView defaultView = lst.DefaultView;
                                defaultView.ViewFields.Add(txtColumnName.Text);
                                defaultView.Update();

                                lst.Update();

                            }
                        }

                        /* get the SPList object by list name*/

                        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }

                    oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Update Successfully");
            }
        }

        private void cmbDataType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Choice") {
                lblMultilime.Visible = true;
                txtMultiline.Visible = true;
                txtMultilineDefault.Visible = true;
                lblMultilineDefault.Visible = true;
            } else {
                lblMultilime.Visible = false;
                txtMultiline.Visible = false;
                txtMultilineDefault.Visible = false;
                lblMultilineDefault.Visible = false;
            }
        }



        private void tbCreateControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void tbUpdatecontrol1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void cmbUpdatevalue_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (cmbUpdatevalue.SelectedItem == "UpdateFormulae") {
                txtmodifiedformulae.Visible = true;
                lblmodiefiedformulae.Visible = true;
            } else {
                txtmodifiedformulae.Visible = false;
                lblmodiefiedformulae.Visible = false;
            }

            if (cmbUpdatevalue.SelectedItem == "RemoveChoice") {
                label8.Visible = true;
                txtRemoveChoice.Visible = true;
            } else {
                label8.Visible = false;
                txtRemoveChoice.Visible = false;
            }

            if (cmbUpdatevalue.SelectedItem == "UpdateText") {
                lbloldvalue.Visible = true;
                lblnewvalue.Visible = true;
                txtOldvalue.Visible = true;
                txtNewvalue.Visible = true;


            } else if (cmbUpdatevalue.SelectedItem == "UpdateChoice") {
                lbloldvalue.Visible = true;
                lblnewvalue.Visible = true;
                txtOldvalue.Visible = true;
                txtNewvalue.Visible = true;
            } else {
                lbloldvalue.Visible = false;
                lblnewvalue.Visible = false;
                txtOldvalue.Visible = false;
                txtNewvalue.Visible = false;
            }

        }

        private void txtOldvalue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void txtNewvalue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void txtmodifiedformulae_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void label8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void txtRemoveChoice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void txtAddChoice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void lblnewvalue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void lbloldvalue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Whenever i run this code to do change in any column the columns i have created before or modified before are created again and again in list.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are not differentiating between when you want to create a new column, and when you want to update the value of a column.

These are two different actions, but your code does not look to see "What is my desired outcome this time: am I creating a new column, or am I updating a column's values?"

So, every time your code runs, it runs *both* the creation *and* update code.

If we look at the beginning of your code we see:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite())
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        foreach (SPWeb subWeb in web.Webs)
        {
            if (it is the web we want)
            {
                SPList list = subWeb.Lists[the list we want];

                // now we have the list we want, on the web we want
```

But at this point, you immediately go into a series of `if` statements that *always* run, and *always* create a new field based on the value of `cmbDataType`:

```
if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Singleline") {
    // create new text field and add it to the list
}
if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Number") {
    // create new number field and add it to the list
}
if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Date") {
    // create new date field and add it to the list
}
if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Multiline") {
    // create new multi-line text field and add it....
}
if (cmbDataType.SelectedItem == "Choice") {
    // create new choice field and add it...
}
```

All that happens before you get to your "update" code.  What you need to do is add some way to indicate which action you want performed (create or update), and only execute the appropriate code blocks based on that selection.